# URL based Movie Streaming App , need help in passing variable strings from one class to another

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I would like to call the value of the `String streamingLink` to 
`String path1 ="xxxxx";` on `MoviePlayerActivity.class` (mentioned below)

Instead of `xxxx`, I need it to be the movie URL

Also, each movie has different URL stored inside an Array of List in DataSources.class

```
public class Movie {

    private String title;
    private String description;
    private int thumbnail;
    private int coverPhoto;
    private String imdb;
    private String rt;
    private String streamingLink;

    //Cast Initializing
    private int cast1;
    private int cast2;
    private int cast3;
    private String actor1;
    private String actor2;
    private String actor3;

    public Movie(String title, int thumbnail, int coverPhoto, String actor1, int cast1, String actor2, int cast2, String actor3, int cast3, String streamingLink, String imdb, String rt, String description) {
        this.title = title;
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
        this.coverPhoto = coverPhoto;
        this.description =description;
        this.imdb = imdb;
        this.rt = rt;
        this.streamingLink = streamingLink;

        // Cast
        this.cast1 = cast1;
        this.cast2 = cast2;
        this.cast3 = cast3;
        this.actor1 = actor1;
        this.actor2 = actor2;
        this.actor3 = actor3;
    }

    public int getCoverPhoto() {
        return coverPhoto;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public int getThumbnail() {
        return thumbnail;
    }

    public String getImdb() {
        return imdb;
    }

    public String getRt() {
        return rt;
    }

    //Cast get activity

    public int getCast1() {
        return cast1;
    }

    public int getCast2() {
        return cast2;
    }

    public int getCast3() {
        return cast3;
    }

    public String getActor1() {
        return actor1;
    }

    public String getActor2() {
        return actor2;
    }

    public String getActor3() {
        return actor3;
    }

    public  String  getStreamingLink() {
        return streamingLink;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public void setCoverPhoto(int coverPhoto) {
        this.coverPhoto = coverPhoto;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setThumbnail(int thumbnail) {
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }


    public void setImdb(String imdb) {
        this.imdb = imdb;
    }

    public void setRt(String rt) {
        this.rt = rt;
    }

    public void setStreamingLink(String streamingLink) {
        this.streamingLink = streamingLink;
    }

    //Cast set activity

    public void setCast1(int cast1) {
        this.cast1 = cast1;
    }
    public void setActor1(String actor1) {
        this.actor1 = actor1;
    }

    public void setCast2(int cast2) {
        this.cast2 = cast2;
    }
    public void setActor2(String actor2) {
        this.actor2 = actor2;
    }

    public void setCast3(int cast3) {
        this.cast3 = cast3;
    }
    public void setActor3(String actor3) {
        this.actor3 = actor3;
    }
}
```

**MoviePlayerActivity:**

```
public class MoviePlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PlayerView playerView;
    FloatingActionButton play_fab;
    private SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        setFullScreen();
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_movie_player );
        hideActionbar();



        iniExoPlayer();
    }

    private void hideActionbar() {

        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }

    private void setFullScreen() {

        requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
        getWindow().setFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );

    }

    private void iniExoPlayer() {
        playerView=findViewById( R.id.movie_exo_player );
        simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance( this );
        playerView.setPlayer( simpleExoPlayer );
        String path1 ="xxxxx";
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory( this,
                Util.getUserAgent(this,"appname"));
        MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory  )
                .createMediaSource( Uri.parse( path1) );
        simpleExoPlayer.prepare( videoSource );
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady( true );

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        simpleExoPlayer.release();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how the array looks like

this is class DataSource

public static List getEnglishMovies(){

```
    List<Movie> lstMovies = new ArrayList<>();
    lstMovies.add( new Movie( "Avengers: Endgame" , R.drawable.avgendgame, R.drawable.avgendgamecp,"Chris Hemsworth",R.drawable.chrishemsworth,"Robert Downey Jr.",R.drawable.downeyjr,"Chris Hemswoth",R.drawable.chrishemsworth,"http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4","8.4","NA","After the devastating events of Avengers: Infinity War (2018), the universe is in ruins. With the help of remaining allies, the Avengers assemble once more in order to reverse Thanos' actions and restore balance to the universe.") );
    lstMovies.add( new Movie( "Extraction" ,R.drawable.extraction, R.drawable.extractioncp,"Chris Hemswoth",R.drawable.chrishemsworth,"Chris Hemswoth",R.drawable.chrishemsworth,"Chris Hemswoth",R.drawable.chrishemsworth,"http://168.61.51.210/movies/Extraction.mp4","6.8","68%","Tyler Rake, a fearless black market mercenary, embarks on the most deadly extraction of his career when he's enlisted to rescue the kidnapped son of an imprisoned international crime lord.") );
    lstMovies.add( new Movie( "The Call Of The Wild" ,R.drawable.thecallofthewildjpg,R.drawable.thecallofthewildcp,"Chris Hemswoth",R.drawable.chrishemsworth,"Chris Hemswoth",R.drawable.chrishemsworth,"Chris Hemswoth",R.drawable.chrishemsworth,"http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4","6.8","62%", "Adapted from the beloved literary classic, THE CALL OF THE WILD vividly brings to the screen the story of Buck, a big-hearted dog whose blissful domestic life is turned upside down when he is suddenly uprooted from his California home and transplanted to the exotic wilds of the Alaskan Yukon during the Gold Rush of the 1890s. As the newest rookie on a mail delivery dog sled team--and later its leader--Buck experiences the adventure of a lifetime, ultimately finding his true place in the world and becoming his own master.") );
    lstMovies.add( new Movie( "Do Little" ,R.drawable.dolittle, R.drawable.dolittlecp,"Chris Hemswoth",R.drawable.chrishemsworth,"Chris Hemswoth",R.drawable.chrishemsworth,"Chris Hemswoth",R.drawable.chrishemsworth,"http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4","5.6","NA","A physician who can talk to animals embarks on an adventure to find a legendary island with a young apprentice and a crew of strange pets.") );

    return lstMovies;
}
```

Comment: Really stuck with the app, Kindly Help